# How can I insert Image on select tag in ionic 4?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic4, scss-lint

Here is my code:

**home.page.html**

```html
    <ion-item>
     <ion-select (click)="loadFlags()" value="select-country" style="max-width: 100%;">
      <ion-select-option value="select-country">select your country </ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country.flag}}">
        {{country.name}}
      </ion-select-option>
     </ion-select>
     <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" [(ngModel)]="number" slot="end"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

**home.page.ts**

```js
    public countries: any = [];

     async getCountries() {
      await this.http.getCounteries()
        .subscribe(countries => {
          // console.log("countries", countries);
          this.countries = countries;
        }, err => {
          // console.log("err", err);
          this.countries = err;
        });
    }

    loadFlags() {
      setTimeout(()=>{ 
        let countries = this.countries;
        // console.log("get countries", countries);
       let radios=document.getElementsByClassName('alert-radio-label');
       for (let index = 1; index < radios.length; index++) {
          let element = radios[index];
          // console.log("element", element);

          // console.log("index", countries[index-1].flag);
          element.innerHTML=element.innerHTML.concat('<img class="country-image" style="width: 30px;height:16px;" src="'+countries[index-1].flag+'" />');
        }
    }, 50);
    }
```

And I want same look like following:

[image]

I have tried all possible solutions. but not any luck.

How can I get same look?. Please guide any code as soon as possible. It would be really appreciated.

I get result as following image:

[image]

I need to display flag image on select instead of country name when selected any country from the options.

Comment: You could use CSS for the flags.

Comment: Please provide some css if you have same about above.

Comment: Kindly refer to these links [Here](https://learncodeweb.com/web-development/icons-show-in-html-select-options/) and [Here](http://thewebfosters.com/add-icons-html-select-options/)

Comment: @ryanc it is not working for me. Actually i m using ionic 4.

Comment: Publish the latest code that you tried that is currently not working.

Comment: Are you getting the image in console logger?

Comment: I am getting image on options in select dropdown.

Comment: I have published the latest code. Please check and give me some solutions to get same result as shown in country flag image

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-inventing this yourself, you might want to try out a community developed solution.

I just did a search and found [ngx-country-picker](https://github.com/guillaume-ro-fr/ngx-country-picker).

You could use it something like this:

```
<country-picker [flag]="true" [setValue]="'callingCode'" [setName]="'name.common'"></country-picker>
```

You can see the full list of available fields in [this related repo](https://github.com/Paldom/angular2-countrypicker), which it lists as the inspiration.